# Django DeleteView - send mail after successful deletion

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I am using DeleteView exactly like explained in the docs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#deleteview

What would be the right method to add an extra `send_mail()` if the deletion was successful?

For example, in CreateView i added it to `form_valid()`

Methods can be found here:

https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.edit/DeleteView/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don’t really have a choice except to use the `delete` method. You can send the email before you return the response.

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = super(YourDeleteView, self).delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
    send_email(...)
    return response
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd extend `delete` method itself. First of all you have the deletion process there and if something goes wrong, you cut the process at a logical place. Secondly it would cause the least possible future confusions when maintaining the code - if it is supposed to happen in relation to deleting, then that would be the reasonable place for it.